# Why are some place holders '@' and others '%'?

Tags: tokens

For example:

```
watchdog('alerts', 'Message for %user was sent.', array('%user' => $user));
```

and

```
drupal_set_message(t('options: @options', array('@options' => $form_state['values'])));
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: This question is, for sure, incorrectly marked as a duplicate. That question (of which this one is NOT a duplicate) is about "Replacement tokens" in the "Message" module (= some technique used in combination with the Rules module), and has nothing to do with what the question is here is about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look into the function definition of the [format_string()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7)
 function which is used by the t() function:

Each type of placeholder has a way in which this function intrepretes it:

```
@variable: Escaped to HTML using check_plain(). Use this as the default choice for anything displayed on a page on the site.
%variable: Escaped to HTML and formatted using drupal_placeholder(), which makes it display as <em>emphasized</em> text.
!variable: Inserted as is, with no sanitization or formatting. Only use this for text that has already been prepared for HTML display (for example, user-supplied text that has already been run through check_plain() previously, or is expected to contain some limited HTML tags and has already been run through filter_xss() previously).
```

Comment: And even though there is no t() function in the first example, the message should use placeholders because it can be translated at a later point.